# Transport object to fragment with RxBus

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm trying to realize RxBus. I'm planning to use it for moving object `Animal` between fragments/activities/dialogs. On code above i try to move my object from Dialog window to `AnswerFragment`, who belong to `QuestionActivity`. I know i can do it without RxBus, but it's in principle.

**RxBus**

```
public class RxBus {
    private static RxBus instance;

    private PublishSubject<Animal> animal = PublishSubject.create();

    public static RxBus instanceOf() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RxBus();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public void setAnimal(Animal sendedAnimal) {
        animal.onNext(sendedAnimal);
    }

    public Observable<Animal> getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }
}
```

I subscribe on RxBus on dialog window:

```
 iv.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            RxBus.instanceOf().setAnimal(animal);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuestionActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            });
```

And try to catch my `Animal` on `AnswerFragment`:

```
 ...
 private Animal currentAnimal;
 ...
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_answer, container, false);

        Disposable disposable = RxBus.instanceOf().getAnimal().subscribe(animal -> currentAnimal = animal);
        disposable.dispose();
```

but my Animal is null, and i don't know why. Intuitively i think it's something about lifecycle. I think that when i write...

```
RxBus.instanceOf().setAnimal(animal);
```

...my `AnswerFragment` is not live yet, so `AnswerFragment` cant take Animal from RxBus, and when `AnswerFragment` subscibe this object already gone. I'm correct? If so, what shall i do?

Comment: Beware that `iv.setOnClickListener(v -> {` did NOT have to run to show `AnswerFragment`, this is why they generally tell you to use the `fragment.setArguments()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject as these subjects offer values previously emitted. PublishSubject will offer to a subscriber only the values emitted after the subscription point.